# how to extract images for every single post in django

Tags: html, django

I have two different models. One is for posts and other one is for images. 
what I want is to display all images for every single post. Here is the file for models:

```
class Cars_Posts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    post_detail = models.TextField(max_length=65536)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s %s %s"(
            self.user.id, self.post_city,
            self.post_title, self.post_detail, self.price,)



class Images_Cars(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Cars_Posts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_images = models.ImageField(upload_to='car_images', blank=True, null=True )


    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s " % (self.post_id, self.car_images, )
```

Here is the view FUNCTION FOR SEARCH (QUERY DATA BASE):

```
def search(request):

    template = 'path/to/template.html'

    # get all cities in data base 
    all_p_cities = City.objects.all()

    #get the exact city selected by user and passed through the variable h_qc
    query_c = request.GET.get('h_qc')

    # get posts under the selected city
    result = Cars__Posts.objects.filter(Q(post_city__city_name__iexact=query_c) 


     # get posts IDs of the result object
    p_id=[] 
    for item in result:
        p_id+= [item.id]
    # print(p_id)


    #get all images under each single post
    all_images=[]
    for item in p_id:
        images = Images_Cars.objects.filter(post_id = item)
        all_images+=[images]



    # print (p_id)
    # print(result)
    print(all_images)


    context = {
        'post_city' : query_c,
        'result': result,
        'all_images':all_images,
    }

    return render(request, template, context )
```

both files run with no error. However in the template I want to display all posts and all images for every single post. I need your help in here. I looped over results and could get all posts. But I got also all images for every single posts repeated in every loop. So , instead of getting only images related to the current post, I got all images for all posts in current post and all subsequent posts. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Also any suggestion for writing the code in view file with an efficient and sophisticated way is appreciated.

Here is portion of the HTML File:

```
                {% csrf_token %}

                {% for item in result %}
                <li class="result-row">
                    <!-- image box -->

                    <span>

                        <a href="#" class="result-image-act" >
                            {% for image in all_images %}
                           <!-- if image list is empty display the default image  -->
                            {% if not image %}
                            <img  src="{% static 'path/to/default image' %}" class="active">

                            {% endif %}
                             <!-- I have class ="active" which is supposed to be class of first image  -->
                            {% if image and image.0 %}
                            <img  class="active" src="{{image.item.car_images.url}}" >

                            {% elif image and not image.0 %}
                            <img  src="{{image.item.car_images.url}}" >
                            {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </a>




                        <span class="embed-result-price">{{item.price}}</span>
                        <div class="swipe-wrap">
                            <div class="swipe-wrap-lef">
                                <span class="move" >
                                    <div class="swipe-prev">
                                        <p>&lt;</p>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swipe-wrap-rig">
                                <span class="move" >
                                    <div class="swipe-next">
                                        <p>&gt;</p>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </span>



                        <span class="result-price">{{result.price}}

</span>
<span class="result-price">{{result.title}}</span>



                </li>

                {% endfor %}
```

Note: inside the html javascript code that will take care of swipe images for every single post that is why I fetch for the first image for every single post to add class="active" to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it directly in templates with *reverse related name*:

**add a property method in your `ImageCars` model to check whether files are actually exist**

```
class Images_Cars(models.Model):
     ''' code '''
     car_images = models.ImageField(upload_to='car_images', blank=True, null=True )

     @property
     def car_images_exists(self):
         return self.car_images.storage.exists(self.car_images.name)
```

**templates**

```
{% for item in result %}

    {% for image in item.images_cars_set.all %}
        #<!-- The images_cars instance is here -->

        {% if image.car_images_exists %} # see changes in models
        {{image.car_images.url}}
        {% endif %}
    {% empty %}
         #<!--Item has no image_cars instances here: item.images_cars_set.all --> 
         <h3>No Images</h3>
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

You don't really need to loop through the queryset in `views` and again in `templates`

`result` as template variable is enough to have everything in templates

Comment: your code is working. can I know how to check if the image is empty for specific post, so I can use the default image?. I used {% if not image %} but it is not working right?

Comment: I use also {% if image is None %}. but still the same. No default image is displayed . I am sure of the path as this src="{% static 'path/to/default image' %}" also I included  {% load staticfiles %}

Comment: do you mean whether the `image` instance is empty *(No Image Cars Instances)* or whether the file `image` actually exists in the server?

Comment: I did both, so you can go with what you want, or you can use them all. see my updates

Comment: Thank you so much Lemayzeur. It works the way I want.